# Aligned equations

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment

I want to have aligned equations going vertically down a page. How do I get this style?

Instead of the following:

```
\[
x_1 + x_2 + x_3


x_2 + x_4 + x_5
\]
```

What how should I do this?

Comment: Use `align` environment.

Comment: Does this mean I have to type begin{equation}\end{equation} for each equation or can I type \\ when i want a new line?

Comment: I tried using \begin{align} \end{align} and now tex won't compile.

Comment: I am using amssym, amsmath, and amsthm

Comment: AFAICT, there is no `amssym` package. Were you trying to load the `amssymb` pacakge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the `align` environment, be sure to load the `amsmath` package in your document's preamble. In the example code below, the "equations" are aligned on the first character (as you didn't provide information on what other point they should be aligned).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} % align* produces unnumbered equations
& x_1 + x_2 + x_3\\
& x_2 + x_4 + x_5
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]